# Eclipse Embedded C/C++ projet from cubeMX makefile

Tags: c, eclipse, makefile, embedded, cubemx

Can someone show me how to import a makefile project from cubeMX into Eclipse the right way? For Indexer to see all methods and variables. Because when I import it either as a makefile project or simply copying files into an empty project, I get errors "Field could not be resolved" for all methods and fields that are in the Drivers directory, although the project compiles successfully.

[image]

I tried to mount the Inc folder but it didn't change anything even if I updated the index. if you import this project as an existing makefile, there are generally several thousand errors

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please take the [tour] to learn how this site works. Please [edit] your question to add new information. -- Why do you have an absolute path in "Includes"? Shouldn't this rather be "${ProjDirPath}/test/..."? -- You need to differentiate between an IDE and its understanding of the source code and the compiler building the program. Both are different beasts. And this is a good thing. ;-)

Comment: I downloaded CubeIDE its faster and simpler than wait for some response as always :D thx for help

Comment: Ok, you added *one* diretcory, what is with the rest, like the Legacy, CMSIS ..., e.g. the rcc.h includes hal_defs.h, which includes something from Legacy. You also gave no hints at all, WHAT these errors are. It could be an error, because these are function-like macros, which use some code, which might be found in the not included directories.